# Reading a particular value from a csv file

Tags: python, csv, text

I need to read a particular value from a csv file. The sample below is the first three line of my input csv file. I need to read the value 60 and save it in a variable.This value can change with every other input csv file.

```
Start Time: 2/21/19 3:50 PM
RDT Sample Rate: 60
"PLEASE NOTE: The sample rate is read...
```

Comment: 1. Do you `must` use pandas? 2. Please put a significative piece of your file.

Comment: Sorry @eusoubrasileiro, Actually I was doing the other things in the csv file using pandas so thought that I can do this as well with pandas. I have edited the question and I have got some interesting piece of codes which is working fine for me. Thanks for stopping by this question and letting me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need pandas for that, a simple function will do the trick :

```
def find_num(path):
    f = open(path)
    f.readline()
    return int(f.readline()[:-1].replace('RDT Sample Rate: ', ''))
```

Comment: Absolutely recommend not to use pandas for just one task that can be done without, as pandas and its dependencies can become quite heavy if you freeze the script

Answer (score 1):

Is this the csv file itself? If so it looks like bad format. I would try

```
Start Time, RDT Sample Rate,

"2/21/19 3:50 PM", "60",
```

and then you should be able to reference what you need to.

Comment: The first 7 lines are kind of basic information about the csv file. So I need to read the value from line 2.